# How to use ">>>" in Dart programming

Tags: dart

[This is a description of the dart documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II2oo.jpg)

But

```
void main() {
  print(3 >>> 1);
}
```

Unable to compile, got an error

`Error: Expected an identifier, but got '>'.`

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is ahead of its time. 
I assume the table comes from https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#operators

Dart removed the `>>>` operator in 2012 when it changed its integer type to arbitrary precision integers (except when compiled to JavaScript). There is no longer a `>>>` operator in Dart, and there haven't been for several years.

In Dart 2.0, Dart changed its integer type to 64-bit integers (still except when compiled to JavaScript). We *plan* to reintroduce the `>>>` operator, and have added it to the language specification, we it has not been implemented by all platforms yet, so it is not available.

The document here was just a little too optimistic about when we release that operator. It won't be in Dart 2.3, as was initially planned.

Comment: Thanks! This comes from https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#operators

Answer (score 0):

For all I know a signpropagating right shift operator in Dart is `a >> b` and not `>>>`. I don't think `>>>` exists. Either your source is incorrect or they have a mistake in their docs.